# Can I use robots.txt to block certain URL parameters?

Tags: robots.txt

Before you tell me 'what have you tried', and 'test this yourself', I would like to note that `robots.txt` updates awfully slow for <del>my site</del>any site on search engines, so if you could provide theoretical experience, that would be appreciated.

For example, is it possible to allow:

```
http://www.example.com
```

And block:

```
http://www.example.com/?foo=foo
```

I'm not very sure.

Help?

Comment: you could try to use a robot emulator, but using **deny** in robots.txt doesn't mean all robots will follow it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard), "The robots.txt patterns are matched by simple substring comparisons" and as the GET string is a URL you should be able to just add:

```
Disallow: /?foo=foo
```

or something more fancy like

```
Disallow: /*?*
```

to disable all get strings. The asterisk is a wildcard symbol so it matches one or many characters of anything.

[Example of a robots.txt with dynamic urls.](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/G7WXqB1MLAw/H92N-aE_CIQJ)

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to block all URLs with `?foo=foo`, not just the base directory?

Comment: Sure if you remove the forward slash it will just match the string anywhere in the URL.

Comment: Note that the `*` wildcard is not part of the original robots.txt specification.